# Python распознаёт строку как число

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, динамическая-типизация

Задача состоит в том, что при получении строки типа: `a3d4c1`, в файл вывести строку: `aaaddddс`. Цифра соответствует количеству повторений символа. Есть код следующего содержания:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    istr = file.readline().strip()

buf = ''
temp = ''
out = open("out.txt", 'w')
for i in istr:
    if i.isdigit():
        #print(type(buf), type(i))
        buf += i
    if i.isalpha() and buf != '':
        out.write(temp*int(buf))
        temp = i
        buf = 0
out.close()
```

Python выдаёт ошибку `unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'` на строке `buf +=i` при этом если убрать комментарий с `print(type(buf), type(i))`, то выдаёт, что оба `str`. В чём ошибка?

Comment: Но вы же сами создали число `buf = 0`, вот на второй итерации и падает

Comment: `''.join([v * int(s[i * 2 + 1]) for i, v in enumerate(s[::2])])`

Comment: Питон может преобразовывать типы в ходе выполнения программы. В данном случае он ошибочно считает что при сложении += пустую строку нужно преобразовать в 0. Поэтому нужно попробовать другие варианты для сложения строк. buf=buf+i или buf=str(buf)+i или buf=buf.join(i)

Comment: @andreymal а почему тогда на каждой из итераций если убрать коммент, пишет, что строка?

Comment: А я вам не верю что на каждой итерации пишет, покажите скриншот например?

Comment: @andreymal https://ibb.co/d4j8vS

Comment: Ну так неинтересно, вы проблемную строку закомментировали и ошибку не воспроизвели)

Comment: @andreymal так с ошибкой он и не собирается :D

Comment: Не собираться он будет только при invalid syntax, а с вашей ошибкой всё будет собираться и печатать как положено (и печатать именно int), но выдавать эту вот ошибку во время выполнения

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы, ошибся, первый новый язык за долгое время изучения плюсов, заговариваюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если комбинации `символ - число` неизменны, то можно так:

```
s = 'a3d4c1'
''.join([v * int(s[i * 2 + 1]) for i, v in enumerate(s[::2])])
# aaaddddc
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, только недавно начал учить язык - пригодится, но вопрос в первую очередь о динамической типизации

Answer (score 1):

Такие строки удобнее парсить регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

s = 'a3d4c1'
print(''.join([c * int(n) for c,n in re.findall(r'([a-z])(\d)', s, flags=re.I)]))
```

Выдаст:

```
aaaddddc
```